# Which is more optimized code?

Tags: c++, performance

```
// (1)
for (int iter = 1; iter <= VERTEX_SIZE; iter ++) {
    if (visit[iter]) continue;
    dfs(iter);
}

// (2)
for (int iter = 1; iter <= VERTEX_SIZE; iter ++) {
    if (!visit[iter]) {
        dfs(iter);
    }
}
```

Which code is more optimized? I'm just curious about it.

Comment: Why not profile it to find out?

Comment: So, you're doing a DFS and you're worrying about one comparison instruction?

Comment: It's no crime to have no idea of how computers, compilers, programming languages, code analysis, code generation, etc. work. But if you lack basic intuition about it, you are simply wasting your time when attempting to "optimize", or reason about performance. Either learn how to do it right, or don't do it. No offense meant, you could just save all of us and yourself a lot of time.

Comment: That's the wrong question. Your job as a coder is to figure out which is the more maintainable (readable). Let the compiler work out how to optimize it correctly.

Comment: Just a comment on the code: in C and C++ (well, okay, Java too) array indices start at 0, so the idiomatic way of writing that loop would be `for(int iter = 0; iter < VERTEX_SIZE; iter ++) ...`. Unless, of course, `visit` has some funky semantics, which is a bad idea because it will confuse anyone who has to maintain the code.

Answer (score 4):

With any even semi-decent compiler this won’t make a difference at all; the generated machine code will be *exactly* the same. If you still want to be sure, benchmark it.

Go for the one you find most *readable*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Pick the one that you thing is the best. Every program you compile with the first way will definitely work with the second way too, and the running time will be the same.

**Note:** I would use the second way; I thing it's more readable and the majority of implementations of DFS I have ever seen (in C++ and in pheudocode) uses it.